# How to pass created element to another function

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

```
 function createElement() {
   const btnCreate = document.createElement('button');
   btnCreate.className = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete';
   const btnValue = document.createTextNode('X');
   btnCreate.appendChild(btnValue);
   const li = document.createElement('li');
   li.className = 'list-group-item';
   const liValue = document.createTextNode(formValue.value);
   li.appendChild(liValue);
   li.appendChild(btnCreate); 
  }

 function addField(li) {
  if(select.value == 'Priority task') {
  prioTask.appendChild(createElement(li));
 } else {
  normalTask.appendChild(createElement(li));
 }
```

i have created a separate function for creating element and to refrain redundancy, i want to pass the "li" variable to the addField. however im getting errors. how to pass created element to another function?

Comment: You're trying to append the `li` element (the one created in `createElement`), right?

Comment: Yes, and the created element which is li is supposed to pass in the addField function

Comment: If you think one of the answer was helpful, mark it as accepted. This is the button below down-up voting

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to call addField with this list element

```
function createElement(){

addField(li);

}
```

Does this help you? If not can you show your error message?

Comment: Umm, the li is created to createElement function. now i want to pass the li created from createElement to the addField function

Comment: Why you call your function the same way like document.createElement()?

Comment: Just trying men, i honestly dont know how to call the created element to another function

Comment: No, I mean there is already a function createElement 
document.createElement()

Comment: Ohh, yes. i have created a element li in createElement function. now the created element from that function was to be pass in the addField function. and then i will insert it in the ul. thats why there is a normalTask.appendChild and prioTask.appendChild. depending on what the user selects.

Comment: @Denyyel You're welcome, if you think this was helpful, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making confusion with parameters. In your code, `createElement` creates an element which is not returned to the other function. You're using `const` whose scope is defined as 'block scoped', which means that variable is only available in the chunk of code where you declared it.
Notice that you don't need to pass `addField` the element just created, you just need to pass the element to `appendChild`. In order to fix this problem, you have to return the newly created element in `createElement` and then pass it to `appendChild` as first parameter.

```
function createElement() {
    const btnCreate = document.createElement('button');
    btnCreate.className = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete';
    const btnValue = document.createTextNode('X');
    btnCreate.appendChild(btnValue);
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'list-group-item';
    const liValue = document.createTextNode(formValue.value);
    li.appendChild(liValue);
    li.appendChild(btnCreate); 

    // Here, you're returning the element to whoever calls the function
    return li;
}

function addField() {
    if(select.value == 'Priority task') {
        // Here, you're passing the element returned by the other function to appendChild
        prioTask.appendChild(createElement());
    } else {
        normalTask.appendChild(createElement());
    }
}
```

In the end you just need to call `addField` and this is what's going to happen:

1. `addField` knows that it has to append a child to `prioTask`, so it checks what's the element he has to append
2. It turns out that you're passing the value returned by `createElement`, therefore the function is executed
3. Once the function is done, it returns the newly created element to the entity that called it
4. At this point, `addField` knows that he has to pass what you've just been returned to `appendChild`

Comment: Hey dude! Thanks a lot. Yeah im being confused at first on what i wrote. but thanks here i finally get it.

Comment: @Denyyel You're welcome, if the answer has been helpful it'd be great to receive an upvote :)

Comment: Already did mate. but it cant be display as of now because im below 15 reputation. thanks again!